# Ext.Date.localToUtc & Ext.Date.utcToLocal must be inverted

Tags: extjs, extjs6

it seems that results from Ext.Date.localToUtc and Ext.Date.utcToLocal must be inverted.

```
var localTime = new Date(); // ROMANIA
var londonTime = Ext.Date.localToUtc(localTime);
console.log('Initial:', localTime);
console.log('London :', londonTime);
console.log('MyTime :', Ext.Date.utcToLocal(londonTime));
console.log('UTC!   :', Ext.Date.format(localTime, 'C'));
```

results for Romania Time zone (GMT+2):

```
Initial: Thu Jan 23 2020 17:48:09 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)
London : Thu Jan 23 2020 19:48:09 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)
MyTime : Thu Jan 23 2020 17:48:09 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)
UTC!   : 2020-01-23T15:48:09.656Z
```

any thoughts?

Comment: I didn't quite catch what's wrong with the results..

Comment: when in Romania is 17:48 in UK is -2h => 15:48 not 19:48:09. so if i change my time in utc (localToUtc it should give me -2h not +2h). meaning it should work as Ext.Date.format(localTime, 'C') does. Only that result seems to be correct.